# Ruby on Rails 5 - Resource gives error when checking if it already exists - whether it does or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to check whether a product already exists or not - if it does, a flash message should appear, with a link to the product that already exists. If not, the product should be created.

The problem is that the flash error is appearing whether the product already exists or not. Where am I going wrong?

products_controller.rb:

```
def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    if @product.product_code.present?
        @existing_product = Product.where(product_code: "#{@product.product_code}").ids.first.to_s
        flash.now[:error] = %Q[This product already exists: <a href="/products/#{@existing_product}">#{@product.product_code}</a>. Please either rename this product or view/edit the existing one.].html_safe
        render 'new'

    elsif @product.save
        redirect_to @product
    else
        render 'new'
    end

end
```

If I try and use the exists? method (rather than present?), I get the following error:

```
undefined method `exists?' for "1234":String
```

1234 is the product code I am trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditional is checking the wrong thing. This:

```
if @product.product_code.present?
```

only checks if `product_code` is present in the `@product` you just made, it does't check if there's anything already in the database with that product code.

I think you want something more like this:

```
@existing_product = Product.find_by(product_code: @product.product_code)
if @existing_product
  flash.now[:error] = ...
  render 'new'
elsif @product.save
  redirect_to @product
else
  render 'new'
end
```

You can use `find_by` to find the thing you're looking for, that will either give you the product or `nil` if there isn't a matching product.

You might want to look into a couple other things:

1. Using the URL helper rather than manually building a link would be better.
2. Your model should be checking the uniqueness of the product codes rather than the controller.
3. As [Dorian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407213/dorian) mentions in the comments, HTML in the flash messages isn't the best idea. You'd be better off checking `@existing_product` in the view and then putting up the link and whatever "complex" error message you need entirely within the view.

Comment: Thanks very much, that works great. I just had to make sure the link was pointing to the id of the existing product, but otherwise worked great. Have been trying to use URL helpers but can't get it to escape the html. Will keep trying!

Comment: You shouldn't put HTML in your flash messages, better use a instance variable and use that in your view, e.g. using `@existing_product` if this case